# Where have all the letters gone?

Tags: 16.04

I run Ubuntu 16.04 on a ThinkPad W541 laptop. I regularly put the laptop in **suspend** mode between uses and things run fine --- but every few weeks, random assortments of all letters will disappear. The following screenshot shows an example, including System Monitor, Terminal, and Nautilus. Emacs 24.5.1 is also affected, but simpler applications (e.g., xterm) are not. A restart fixes everything until the next time this happens. Any ideas on how to

(a) avoid this altogether or at least

(b) fix the problem without restarting?

[image]

EDIT: the image above doesn't display properly, but can be seen [here](https://people.ucsc.edu/~ianc/images/missingletters.png).

EDIT2: This happened to me again a few days ago. No-one has run into this or has suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is [bug 1573959](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1573959).  The workaround is to upgrade to a later kernel:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```